# How to setup Tika parser to detect password protected docs

Tags: scala, pdf, password-protection, apache-tika

We are using Apache Tika parser to extract content from various docs and also to detect if a document is password protected (PDF, MS Office docs, etc). With Tika 1.6 we used the following Scala code (simplified):

```
val stream: InputStream = ...

val textHandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1)  // unlimited write buffer
val metadata = new Metadata()
val parser = new AutoDetectParser(new DefaultDetector())

val text = parser.parse(stream, textHandler, metadata, new ParseContext())
```

and were catching either `EncryptedDocumentException` or `CryptographyException` wrapped into `TikaException`.

It used to work ok, but the detection got broken when we upgraded Tika to 1.7. For instance, now for protected PDFs we are getting plain `IOException`wrapped into `TikaException`:

```
java.io.IOException: null
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.decode(FlateFilter.java:109) ~[tika-app-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.doDecode(COSStream.java:379) ~[tika-app-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.doDecode(COSStream.java:291) ~[tika-app-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.getUnfilteredStream(COSStream.java:225) ~[tika-app-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser.<init>(PDFStreamParser.java:117) ~[tika-app-1.7.jar:1.7]
Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:259) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:280) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.decompress(FlateFilter.java:128) ~[tika-app-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.decode(FlateFilter.java:101) ~[tika-app-1.7.jar:1.7]
```

What are we missing in the Tika parser setup to properly detect the protected docs?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Maybe this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1548 - or similiar/related?

Comment: @MikeCurry - thank you! that's probably it. I haven't tested with the Tika trunk, but I saw the fix in the right place. Now I have to wait for Tika 1.8 to be released :(

Comment: glad to help. I just raised it to an answer so that if anyone else experiences the same issue with 1.7 it will be more immediately obvious than in the comments. As noted in the answer, it might be possible to apply a patch locally as the source is open if you can't wait for 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to be 100% certain but this issue is likely caused by or related to:

http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1548

This issue is present in 1.7 but appears to be resolved on the main branch for 1.8

The great thing about open source is that it is well, open, so if required it should be possible to patch the issue locally with a local build until the official 1.8 release.